# I am currently working on a class assignment, In CodingBat, And I am getting numerious compile errors and "list index out of range"

Tags: python-3.x

Given an array of ints, return True if the array is length 1 or more, and the first element and the last element are equal.

same_first_last([1, 2, 3]) → False
same_first_last([1, 2, 3, 1]) → True 
same_first_last([1, 2, 1]) → True

My solution, was as follows:

```
def same_first_last(nums):
    if (nums[0] == nums[(len(nums))-1]==6):
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

Well, that did not work, so I tried:

```
def same_first_last(nums):
  if (nums[0] == (nums[nums.length]) - 1):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Still no luck, now I am getting this error: 
 "'list' object has no attribute 'length'" 
 Any advice?

> The Hint Given Was:
>  
> The length is nums.length, the first element is nums[0] and the last element is nums[nums.length - 1]

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple.

```
def same_first_last(nums):
    if not nums: return False # if the array is empty
    return nums[0] == nums[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to your method,follow this:

```py
def same_first_last(nums):
  if (nums[0] == (nums[nums.size()-1]):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```